# What does "correctly noded" mean?

Tags: postgis, terminology

I've never seen this term, and I'm wondering what it means, with regard to [`ST_Polygonize`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Polygonize.html)

> NOTE: Input linework must be *correctly noded* for this function to work properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[this page](http://www.h2gis.org/docs/1.3/ST_Polygonize/) helpfully shows some of the edge cases where this function would fail and return NULL. To summarise some examples...

- two linestring geometries which touch/cross at one point. but don't loop back on each other to touch/cross at another point
- two disjoint lines
- a single linestring which does't form a complete loop

or any case where the set/array of geometries doesn't form one or more polygons. Also, rounding/precision errors might come into play, and it may be that linestrings need to align in a consistent direction.

there may be other definitions of 'incorrectly noded' :)